# Calling super with a non nullable Key

Tags: flutter

since upgrading to the new version I am trying to bring in null safety.

I don't quite understand how I call to the super constructor with a non nullable Key.

The error I am receiving (obviously involving the Key) is "The argument type 'Key' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'LocalKey?'."

The class I am trying to create worked fine before, and setting the Key as either nullable with a '?' or setting the Key as 'required' in the constructor doesn't seem to work either.

```
class FadeAnimationPage extends Page {
  final Widget? child;

  FadeAnimationPage({Key key, this.child}) : super(key: key); <----- This is the line with error

  Route createRoute(BuildContext context) {
    return PageRouteBuilder(
      settings: this,
      pageBuilder: (context, animation, animation2) {
        var curveTween = CurveTween(curve: Curves.easeIn);
        return FadeTransition(
          opacity: animation.drive(curveTween),
          child: child,
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Thanks for any help you can provide.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to swap `Key` with `LocalKey` in your constructor as that's the one specified in `Page`'s constructor signature. `LocalKey` is an implementation of `Key`, you can't use these two interchangeably

```
FadeAnimationPage({required LocalKey key, this.child}) : super(key: key);
```

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Page/Page.html

Comment: Ok thanks, I did that as you said, and also added '?'. So now the full line is   FadeAnimationPage({LocalKey? key, this.child}) : super(key: key);

Comment: ah yes, I've updated the answer. sorry for that!